# Jmeter Json Extractor: JSONPath Expression works on evaluators but not inside jmeter?

Tags: json, jmeter, extractor

I'm facing issue with a jsonpath to extract element from json.

Here is an example of the json:

```
[
   {
      "idA":"104",
      "idB":"2941",
      "idC":"13316",
      "idE":"13361",
      "idF":"12758",
      "idG":"12865",
      "idH":[
         
      ]
   },
   {
      "idA":"104",
      "idB":"2941",
      "idC":"13317",
      "idE":"13362",
      "idF":"12759",
      "idG":"12866",
      "idH":[
         "10391"
      ]
   },
   {
      "idA":"104",
      "idB":"2941",
      "idC":"13318",
      "idE":"13363",
      "idF":"12760",
      "idG":"12867",
      "idH":[
         
      ]
   }
]
```

Here is the jsonpath:

```
$[?(@.idH[0]!=null)]
```

The goal is to get the element where idH is not null.
It works on few json online evaluators from whom I get what I expected:

```
[
    {
        "idA": "104",
        "idB": "2941",
        "idC": "13317",
        "idE": "13362",
        "idF": "12759",
        "idG": "12866",
        "idH": [
            "10391"
        ]
    }
]
```

But it fails on others few online evaluators too, returning for example "An error occurred with JSONPath."

Unfortunately, it doesn't work with Json extractor in Jmeter, because I get the first element of the json, like if the jsonpath would have been $[0]

Any Idea what is the problem here?
Thanks in advance for any help, clue or idea.

For information in case, I use Apache JMeter (5.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) which allows executing arbitrary [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) queries

You should be able to get the object you're looking for as simple as:

```
$..[?(@.idH[0])]
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Well in fact I already use Json Extractor on Jmeter, but it was all about the Jsonpath expression. Because I tried to add in the search part: @.idH[0]!=null       To get every element where first idH array element is not null. I guess that in a Jsonpath expression you cannot directly formulate the negation, is it right?